# Unable to save the data in Solr custom indexes

Tags: solr, indexing

Working on `Solr 8.1.1` with `Sitecore 9.3`, And created the `custom indexes` but unable to save the data in those indexes.
Please find the below configuration for custom indexes made:

```
<contentSearch><configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="targeting_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="core">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />           
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" />

        <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          </policies>
        </commitPolicyExecutor>            
      </index> <indexes></configuration>
  <indexConfigurations>
    <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
      <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
        <typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
          <typeMatch typeName="doubleCollection"   type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double]"   fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdm"  multiValued="true"                    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
        </typeMatches>
        <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
          <field fieldName="subwaypersonid" returnType="int"  />
          <field fieldName="storeid" returnType="int"  />
          <field fieldName="tags" returnType="stringCollection"  />
        </fieldNames>
      </fieldMap>                           
    </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
  </indexConfigurations>
</contentSearch>
```

Used the above configuration for `Custom indexing`, Done indexing using `Indexing Manager`. But unable to retrieve the results in `Solr`.

Could anyone please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: Could you please share full xml for Solr from showconfig.aspx?

Comment: Did you create the index in Solr?

Comment: Yes... Created the index in Solr and I am able to see in Solr Admin panel

Comment: Hi, in your index configuration you need to have a definition for the crawler, what items to be added in your index. Example: <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <customCrawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content</Root>
              </customCrawler >
            </locations>

Comment: Make sure to populate the managed schema and reindex. From there, keep an eye on the Solr logs.